# Painting on old lime plaster

Tags: painting

I have recently stripped the wallpaper off the hall internal walls. The house is old (Edwardian) so has lime plaster underneath which is in good condition. I would like to paint directly on to the walls - do I need to do any wall preparation and what paint should I use?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firm plaster should be reattached with plaster washers and drywall screws. Fix damage areas with patching for use on plaster and apply an oil-based or shellac primer to seal out moisture. Follow with a top-quality latex paint to give your old plaster a new look.

Comment: thanks very much for this response i got it replastered and it looks great